# Flutter: Lazy build in scrollview

Tags: flutter, scrollview, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to build scrollview that has different kind of widgets like images ,text and rows.
The problem is I want widgets start build (rendering) when it comes on screen not at startup.

Comment: Have you checked [example in the official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)?

Comment: Have you seen this [example for loading list lazily](https://medium.com/@archelangelo/flutter-load-contents-lazily-on-scroll-made-simple-c6817f94e5d0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ListView.builder()`.

```dart
List<Widget> someItems;

...

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: someItems.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return someItems[index];
  },
)
```